# How to use functions from sklearn into pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, scikit-learn, bigdata, apache-spark-mllib

I have a training set with 201,917 rows, 3 features and 1 target. My aim is to calculate the strength of the relationship of the individual features with the target. My choice of method for this is `sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression` because it works for continuous variables and can detect non-linear relationships better than the counterpart `sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression`. This is the line I tried to run -

```
feature_selection.mutual_info_regression(trainPD[['feature_1']],trainPD['target'])
```

Now the problem is if I run `sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression` in Colab, the system crashes. Hence my idea was to shift to pyspark. But `pyspark.ml` does not have support for `sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression`. So what are my options to use `sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression` in `pyspark`?

I am not sure if `pandas_udf` will help because here it is not the traditional `pd.Series -> pd.Series` conversion where `pyspark` parallelization works.

Comment: Well, I think you answered the question all by yourself. If the regression you need does not exist in Spark, you can always add it as a scala package.

Comment: @Steven, I am not that well versed in Pyspark and not at all in SCALA. Hence could you please elaborate on what is this 'adding as a scala package' denote? Is there a Python equivalent for it? If you can refer me to any sort of possible material it will be great. Thanks.